# Создание обтекаемой формы

Tags: javascript, html, css

Добрый вечер, хочу поприветствовать всех пользователей сайта ХэшКод и Администрацию в том числе. Я относительно недавно начал изучать язык программирования "Php". Я узнал много нового из учебного издания. Также, посещая сайты я вижу прекрасные обтекаемые формы для ввода данных. Я знаю, как создать самую простую форму, но считаю её "непривлекательной". Прошу Вас, если Вы знаете, рассказать о том, как создать форму с закруглёнными краями.    Было бы восхитительно, если бы Вы разместили синтаксис в комментариях.

Comment: Кстати, красивые формы - это HTML, CSS и, быть может, JS, но не PHP.

Answer (score 2):

[38 статей о закругленных углах](http://vremenno.net/html-css/38-articles-about-creating-rounded-corners/) 2-строчка по запросу в гугле.

Comment: по-моему всё проще:
    
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;

Comment: @Spectre, а как же

    -o-border-radius: 20px;

=(

Comment: а как же всеми любимый ie 6 ?

Comment: в опере обычный `border-radius` прекрасно работает

Comment: @Spectre, буду знать.
@FLK, ай-ай-ай, сравнивать Оперу и ИЕ6)

Comment: @Construct а теперь внимательно читаем комментарии и пытаемся найти место где я сравниваю ie6 и оперу